# pass data between pages react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have `eventData` which I need to pass from page A to B. Here's my code:

```
function eCE(eventData) {

    history.push({
      pathname: '/ece',
      state: eventData
   })

})
```

This function gets triggered on button click, so it passed `eventData` through to the function. Now I need to send `eventData` through to the next page, in which I would get to by calling `/ece`. However, I am trying to grab the `state` on the other page like so:

```
const { state } = this.props.location
console.log(state)
```

it isn't working, and the error I get is:

```
TypeError: undefined has no properties
```

not to sure what to do here. appreciate the help !

Comment: can you provide codesanbox ?

Comment: @AmanSadhwani would codepen suffice?

Comment: Any online executable format is fine @devdude19289 just so we can see where the error is occurring.

Comment: you can refer my repo https://github.com/amansadhwani/auto-logout-react/tree/main/src    check these two files dashboard and user from dashboard I am sending data to user.

Comment: @AmanSadhwani thanks for the repo. Very informative, the only problem is I am still on the version which uses useHistory instead of useNavigation, so it isn't working. But good to know for future use :)

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you've shared. Can you provide a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page 1:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function page1(){   
  const history = useHistory();

  const goToPage2 = () => {
    history.push("/page2", { age: 18 });
  }
  return <button onClick={goToPage2}>Go To Page2</button>
}
```

In page 2:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function page2(){ 
  const location = useLocation();
  return <div><p>{location.state.age}</p></div>
}
```